# Haw can I do for making button show me fileupload

Tags: primefaces

haw can I do for diplay fileupload when I press a commande button.

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-refresh" onclick="data.show()"></p:commandButton>
```

this is my Fileupload

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="t" >
                   <p:fileUpload  auto="true" disabled="true" id="data"
                   fileUploadListener="#{composantbean.handleFileUpload}"
                   sizeLimit="2097152"
                   label="Choose"
                   allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/"
                   description="Images"/> 
                 </h:form>
```

on this solution the file uplad is displayed ..haw can I do

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your need. You want to display the `p:fileUpload` only after you click the `p:commandButton`?

If so, you need to create a boolean variable in your bean(controller) and when clicking on the button, set it `true`. It would look like this:

.xhtml

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-refresh" action="#{testController.renderFileUpload()}" update="@this"/>

  <p:fileUpload auto="true" id="data" rendered="#{testController.isRenderFU()}"
               fileUploadListener="#{composantbean.handleFileUpload}"
               sizeLimit="2097152"
               label="Choose"
               allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/"
               description="Images"/>
```

testController

```
...
private boolean renderFU = false;

public void renderFileUpload(){
    renderFU = true;
}

public boolean isRenderFU() {
    return renderFU;
}

public void setRenderFU(boolean renderFU) {
    this.renderFU = renderFU;
```

Comment: My problem consist ..I would like to display 3 button the first one for updating file the other one for showing details and the last for uploading file ..I wont when the user press the button for uplaoding a file fileupload is diplay ..

Comment: You must do something wrong. It's the same approache on every component if you want to display it only after clicking a certain button.